# how to highlight specific string using html in android

Tags: android, html, highlight

I am developing android.

I want to mark search results like below.

```
String keyword =  = input.getText().toString();

holder.textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(mData.get(position)
                        .getPrefText()
                        + "<span class=\"marked\">"
                        + mData.get(position).getKeyword()
                        + "</span>"
                        + mData.get(position).getPostText()));
```

keyword is between Strings And I want to mark only keyword.

I want to set the keyword background color yellow.

I tried some html grammars but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't truly support HTML in TextViews. It supports a limited subset of html to allow some minor styiling, and things like links. Unfortunately to get spans of text with different styles, you currently have to do it fully programatically. IE, create a SpannableString and give it style information and add it to a TextView. The process is detailed here

http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring

Interestingly enough, this is alot like iOS does it.